# Cryptology ePrint and arXiv

Tags: arxiv

I'm a relatively new researcher, and I'm confused as to what exactly sites like arXiv and cryptology ePrint are and what people use them for. Are they simply archives where you can upload any research paper related to the field? Does your paper have to be in a journal/conference in order to upload them? Will you have to submit your paper to a journal or conference after uploading to arXiv? What are the incentives for someone upload to these archives? Are papers on these sites considered to be "published"?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please ask one question per post.  In the help section, you will see that duplicate questions and questions that do not show research are not permitted.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/133546/13240

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11161/what-qualifies-as-a-research-publication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, arXiv is a place where people store their preprints. No these papers are not published because these are not peer-reviewed. This is used to announce new results mostly because it may take a lot of time for publication to appear. Some preprints are never published. So people should be careful when referring to them. But if one is sure the results are correct, one can refer to a preprint. For example, it usually is the case when one refers to his/her own preprint.

Comment: How about we start saying "no, they're not peer-reviewed, but, literally, they are published, in the sense of being available to the public"? :)

Comment: @paulgarrett: No these are not published (which is a well defined notion.) Yes, preprints are available to the public. Before arXiv there were similar storages of paper versions of preprints. After the beginning of the Internet, people uploaded preprints to their Web pages. ArXiv is much more convenient, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Wait, so does this mean there could be a bunch of papers in arXiv that where never published but sit around there (i.e. the paper was rejected by a journal or something and the researcher did not continue with the project)?

Comment: @eliyablon: There are many texts in the arXiv which contain errors, many texts which have been rejected from journals, and some texts (including pretty famous ones like Perelman's preprints about the Poincare conjecture) which were never submitted to a journal.

Comment: @markvs, so, the academic world has permanently hijacked the verb "publish" to mean "peer-reviewed, ..."? I understand that this is conceivably the case, but to me, by this year, it is a bit obnoxious. But, sure, other people have other opinions...

Comment: @paulgarrett: You may want to show respect to academic world and not use charged words like "hijacked". In some sense, preprints of Perelman are publication because these were peer-reviews. Same for the famous preprint of Hrushovski.

Comment: @markvs, I think I understand your point, but I disagree that it is showing disrespect to want to disavow "published" as meaning what it seems to mean for some academics. I calculate that I'm enough of an academic myself, with enough conventional credentials (if that's what it takes), to have a legitimate opinion. I'm not saying this in an angry way, at all, so please don't misunderstand, but I do think that the status-protecting, tenure-guarding, etc. features corrupt the mathematical-progress aspects. I'd be happy to discuss this in person, if things ever offer that. Best wishes. -pg

Comment: ... and, in the context of these days, it'd be great to have a civil argument over a glass of wine or beer about mathematical things, etc. Damn friggin' frustrating to not see people in person...

Comment: @paul garrett - Tangentially related, but I believe that in the "old days," (around the 1960s) mathematicians did math for fun, as a luxury. But now that it is something we try to make a career out of -- becoming a mathematician has been *demoted* to a status-seeking, tenure-getting competition.

Comment: In the arXiv there two papers (in fact, more then two) proving opposite things, one proves "yes", another proves "no" answer to a famous problem). You consider both papers publications?

Comment: @cgb5436: That is not quite correct, https://sueishaqlab.org/2021/03/26/a-brief-history-of-the-brief-history-of-academic-tenure/#:~:text=Tenure%20is%20a%20permanent%20and,legislation%20began%20to%20pop%20up.

Comment: The (minority) traditional meaning *in academia* of "publish"/"publication" is long obsolete - the words do now relate to "being available to the public". Putting work on to a pre-print server is publishing it; hence the accompanying palaver about copyright and licences. With [Altmetrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altmetrics) and such now, even a Tweet can be counted as a "publication"!

Comment: > *Before arXiv there were similar storages of **paper** versions of preprints.* Really? I don't recall ever seeing such a library. Can you give any examples? (**pre**prints might occasionally have got left lying on the coffee-room table, and the group/department might keep a collection of those it had produced, but I'm not aware of anyone making a collection of third-party preprints accessible. Ethical issues for a start.) It's been a long time: are you confusing with **off**-prints (which *were* intended for circulation, with some conditions).

Answer (score 3):

It is certainly true that there are wildly varying opinions about "putting things online" without being vetted by "authorities".

Yes, due to tradition, "published" in many peoples' minds means "peer-reviewed" (no matter whether it is available except behind a paywall or not, etc.) I have come to think that people should say "peer-reviewed" if that's what they mean.

The word "published", in academic circles, has come to mean "peer-reviewed". Ok, but, well, how about just saying "peer-reviewed", rather than corrupting the "publicly-available" sense of "published"?

There is also the implied sense that without peer-review, things are suspect. Ok, sure, some people with dubious judgement do make things public. On the other hand, passing the gate-keeping aspect of "peer-review" is a bit corrupted, and involves things apart from the intellectual/scientific merits of the thing at hand. As in the explicit question from editors to referees about whether the manuscript at hand is sufficiently ... something ... for the journal. :)

(Also, btw, several journals have told me, as referee, that it's not my responsibility to check for correctness, though I tend to! So, "peer-reviewed" does not promise correctness! More often, the result is completely unsurprising, or completely expected, anyway, ... and, as I've said before, false proofs of true theorems are seldom debunked/corrected, and there's seldom much enthusiasm about it. :)

So, if a person wants to make their ideas public, in math, yes, arXiv is excellent. I look at it every day, as do many. No, the thresh-hold for getting things on there is low, so the mere appearance there has no status points nor certification of anything. But lots of people will see it.

EDIT: and you will establish priority, I think, if that matters!

Similarly, if you've been around for a long time, putting things on your own web-page will reach many people, too. Again, no status-points scored. :)

I gather that high-energy physics has shifted in their way of thinking about "publication" far more than math has...

:)

Comment: > "peer-reviewed" does not promise correctness. I thought that if something got published, it must be correct! :)

Comment: @cgb5436, well, being filtered through some sort of refereeing is an upvote for the plausibility of the result. If it's non-controversial, and anticipated to be a true assertion, then it is probably correct. :)